# why post request has different result?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, asana-api

I have use curl in linux to post data to asana and its work fine.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <mytoken>" https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/101/stories -d "text=hello world"
```

but if I use requests library for python the result is 400

```
response = requests.post("https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/101/stories", auth=(self.asana.token_uri, ""), params = "text=repo_name")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the same "Authorization: Bearer" token header to your request in python. Similar to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29931730/6080374

Answer (score 0):

The `auth` argument to `requests` methods produces a `Authorization: Basic` header, not a `Authorization: Bearer` header.

Set a `headers` dictionary with a manually created `Authorization` header instead. POST data (the `-d` command line switch for curl) should be passed as a dictionary to the `data` argument:

```
response = requests.post(
    "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/101/stories",
    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(self.asana.token_uri),
    data={'text': 'repo_name'})
```