# How to access token based API using requests module in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I want to call one API from another API. So external API is having jwt token based authentication .

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://host:port/api/users', auth= ("username","password"))
```

I am getting error :

```
{"error":"authentication failed: jwt parse error: token contains an invalid number of segments","code":16,"message":"authentication failed: jwt parse error: token contains an invalid number of segments","details":[]}
```

Or , First i need to call login API ,get the token and while calling another API apply that token in header. If it so then why 'auth' param is there in `requests.get(URL, auth=(username,password))`?

Comment: Do you know when the token expires? If it expires frequently, you may have to call login API and get the token.

Comment: Did you get the token? if yes then prefix "Bearer " to the token value and pass as authorization header in the next request (Note the space after bearer) . You can add headers as specified here https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers

Comment: FYI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931671/making-an-api-call-in-python-with-an-api-that-requires-a-bearer-token

Comment: @Sri  , Token will expire in some time. If you have to call login API in order to get token then what is the use of 'auth' param in requests.get(URL, auth=(username,password))?

Comment: @Luv please find my above comment .

Comment: Usually auth API is a post request. Can you reconfirm it is a get. Then the server should not be looking for a token.

Comment: @Luv Actually i need to call a API which auth token. For get request also same error will come because its required auth token.

Comment: The auth request you are making, try requests.post instead of requests.get and then use that auth token you receive in further API calls.

Comment: @Luv Fetching token from login api and pass it in another api header will work , but my point here is "what is the use of 'auth' param in requests.get(URL, auth=(username,password))?"

Answer (score 0):

Here is (from a high-level point of view) the mechanism behind requests:

When the request is constructed `request(method, url, **kwargs)` only the method and url arguments are mandatory the rest are optional:

`:param auth: (optional) Auth tuple to enable Basic/Digest/Custom HTTP Auth.`

Afterwards from the methods perspective:

```py
def get(url, params=None, **kwargs):
    r"""Sends a GET request.
    :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
    :param params: (optional) Dictionary, list of tuples or bytes to send
        in the query string for the :class:`Request`.
    :param \*\*kwargs: Optional arguments that ``request`` takes.
    :return: :class:`Response <Response>` object
    :rtype: requests.Response
    """

    kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

def post(url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs):
    r"""Sends a POST request.
    :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
    :param data: (optional) Dictionary, list of tuples, bytes, or file-like
        object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
    :param json: (optional) json data to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
    :param \*\*kwargs: Optional arguments that ``request`` takes.
    :return: :class:`Response <Response>` object
    :rtype: requests.Response
    """

    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
```

For `get` and `post` mandatory argument is the url and the others are default or optional.

Many web services may require authentication like **HTTP Basic Auth**. This is the simplest kind, and Requests supports it straight out of the box.

```py
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requests.get('http://host:port/api/users', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

Which is the same with

```py
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requests.get('http://host:port/api/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

So basically it's very important how the API was implemented from the authentication point of view (HTTPBasicAuth, HTTPDigest Authentication, OAuth1). Based on this you can use the appropriate module(within `requests`) in order to authenticate.

Hope this helps

Comment: Fetching token from login api and pass it in another api header will work , but my point here is "what is the use of 'auth' param in requests.post(URL, auth=(username,password))?"

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. In my case Bearer Authentication token is used by the API which i need to call . So Which one will preferred to use (HTTPBasicAuth, HTTPDigest Authentication, OAuth1) ?