# Making an API request in Python with a token - syntax error

Tags: python, ajax, curl

I am new-ish to Python and am trying to use an API in my Jupyter notebook, which requires a token. The API is from NOAA.

I put my request in the format given on [NOAA's website](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2). Everything below is literally what I put in my code with the exception of the token itself, replaced as MYLONGTOKEN:

```
curl -H "token:<MYLONGTOKEN>" "https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/stations"
$.ajax({ url:<url>, data:{<data>}, headers:{ token:<token> } })
```

I get back a syntax error pointing at the " after MYLONGTOKEN. I have tried taking it out of the brackets and quotes, adding spaces, etc but can't seem to get rid of the error. I'm also not clear if the < token > on the second line is supposed to be replaced with the actual token, but I haven't gotten past the error in the first line to find out.

I also tried following a different syntax offered on [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931671/making-an-api-call-in-python-with-an-api-that-requires-a-bearer-token) but that gave me a JSONDECODE error.

I'm using python3 and wondering if NOAA's code might be outdated.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any Python code.

Comment: You say that everything is literally what you put in other than the token, but clearly you are meant to substitute actual values for each of the `<....>` items.

Comment: Anyway I don't think you are meant to include the `.ajax` stuff, this is an alternative, not part of the curl command.

Comment: In addition to to the previous comments: please add the error message.

Comment: If you are trying to call from python, you will want to use `requests` library and use `headers` parameter wth dictionary containing `{'token': 'XxYyZz.....'}' or whatever.  I'll add an answer in a moment with an actual example....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example Python code:

```
import requests

token = "setljksetaafjlkasetaljksetasetdt"  # not a real access key obviously

url = "https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/stations"

response = requests.get(url, headers={'token': token})

data = response.json()
results = data["results"]

print("num results {}".format(len(results)))

for result in results[:2]:  # show first two results
    print()
    for k, v in result.items():
        print("{} => {}".format(k, v))
```

Output:

```
num results 25

elevation => 139
elevationUnit => METERS
mindate => 1948-01-01
longitude => -85.2482
name => ABBEVILLE, AL US
datacoverage => 0.8813
id => COOP:010008
latitude => 31.5702
maxdate => 2014-01-01

elevation => 249.3
elevationUnit => METERS
mindate => 1938-01-01
longitude => -87.1814
name => ADDISON, AL US
datacoverage => 0.5059
id => COOP:010063
latitude => 34.2553
maxdate => 2015-11-01
```

Note: presumably the different endpoints return different structures inside the JSON.  The above is an example based on what I found using the `stations` URL that you quoted in the question.  Look inside the data returned from `response.json()` to see what you get, as I don't know whether the results from all the different endpoints necessarily contain an element called `'results'`.

The point of the `curl ...` thing in their documentation would be that *if* you were going to call from the Linux command line instead of in a Python script, you would do something like:

```
curl -H "token:setljksetaafjlkasetaljksetasetdt" "https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/stations"
```

so what this is saying (because the `-H` option in curl is for adding headers) is that you need to add an http request header called `token`, which in the Python code above is implemented using the dictionary that is passed via the `headers` parameter to the `requests.get` call.

And separately, on the next line, they also give an example of access via an Ajax call.

Comment: Thanks so much! I h ad no idea what ajax or curl were for, so I appreciate the explanation.