# Python get API responses using Bearer Token

Tags: python, python-requests, bearer-token

I have checked all examples but none shows endpoint like mine. How do I access API with endpoint such that :

```
end_point = f"https://something.com/version/input1/{0}/input2/{1}".format(payload["input1"], payload["input2"])

api_token = {"authorization": "Bearer LonGTokEN"}
    
api_response = requests.post(url=end_point, auth=api_token['authorization'])
```

I'm getting `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`. Based on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931671/making-an-api-call-in-python-with-an-api-that-requires-a-bearer-token), I need `data` but I'm not sure how I should do it with my endpoint.

Also, unsure if the bearer token is called correctly or not.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: remove `f`? I'm getting `405` error

Comment: Can you provide the endpoint details so it's reproducible? Yes, your payload should be part of your `data` input.

Comment: At least an HTTP error is different from a Python error. 405 is saying a POST is not allowed

Comment: Are you including the word "bearer" or "Bearer" in your Auth? Asking to make sure.

Comment: `405` is the error returned by the server, you need to look if you are passing the right combination of data, token, url, etc.

Comment: I  use `Bearer`. The endpoint should produce a json result.

Comment: Since you have no request body, are you sure that you want a POST request?

Comment: @OneCricketeer youre right. Ive modified my code using `get` and now it worked!

Answer (score 1):

OK. That was silly of me. I've made changes on my code seems to work.

```
class BearerAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token
    def __call__(self, r):
        r.headers["authorization"] = "Bearer " + self.token
        return r

def test_api_no_pax(mock_input, expected_output):
    """
    Testing API after deployment (no pax)
    """
    with open(f"./assets/{mock_input}.json") as json_file:
        payload = json.load(json_file)

    end_point = "https://something.com/version/input1/{0}/input2/{1}".format(payload["input1"], payload["input2"])

    api_token = {"authorization": "LonGTokEN"} # removed Bearer since I use BearerAuth

    api_response = requests.get(url=end_point, auth=BearerAuth(api_token['authorization']))
    print(api_response.text)
```

Though I wish for cleaner code without having to write `BearerAuth`. Better solution is highly encouraged!

EDIT:
Without using `BearerAuth` class.

```
api_token = {"authorization": "Bearer LonGTokEN"}
api_response = requests.get(url=end_point, headers=api_token)
```

Comment: just for my confirmation, does having both `f-strings` and `format()` work as is? I would expect it to throw error you posted in the question.

Comment: You shouldn't need a class. Just change `auth` param to `headers` and pass the "api token" dictionary (which is actually request headers) with the Bearer part added back

Comment: @OneCricketeer you're right again! Thank you :)

Comment: Please fix the f-string/format issue. That's why you get a str vs int error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is mixing `f-string` with `format`.

You need to use one of them:

```
end_point = "https://something.com/version/input1/{0}/input2/{1}".format(payload["input1"], payload["input2"])
```

or:

```
end_point = f"https://something.com/version/input1/{payload['input1']}/input2/{payload['input2']}"
```

Comment: I tried and it seems to contributed to get error. So I changed as your recommendation (Y)