# Alexa fetching user email using python

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to make an Alexa skill using python backend.
I am using amazon developer console to create model and code backend.

I want to retrieve user email address.
I would appreciate if you could provide me with sample code. I tried many methods but none were working.

here are some codes I tried :
https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-python/tree/master/samples/GetDeviceAddress

I know this is device address but this was also not working, and I thought if i could get address I can get email.

Everything mentioned online is for Node, and I want to make my backend on python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As specified in the official documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-customer-contact-information-for-use-in-your-skill.html#get-customer-contact-information) you need to make an API call to the ASK.

For email you need to call your api_endpoint followed by `/v2/accounts/~current/settings/Profile.email`

For me endpoint is : `https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com` therefore the complete url becomes :
[https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com/v2/accounts/~current/settings/Profile.email](https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com/v2/accounts/%7Ecurrent/settings/Profile.email)

As far as adding the token to authorize the request it can be done by using the requests library by passing header to the get request. [You can learn more about that from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931671/making-an-api-call-in-python-with-an-api-that-requires-a-bearer-token)

The final code should then look something like this :

```
    #Fetching access token
    accesstoken = str(handler_input.request_envelope.context.system.api_access_token)

    #Fetching user emailaddress from ASK API
    endpoint = "https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com/v2/accounts/~current/settings/Profile.email"
    api_access_token = "Bearer " + accesstoken 
    headers = {"Authorization": api_access_token}
    r = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)
    email = r.json()
```

Hope this helps, Cheers!