# How to get token from API with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests, token

I need to get token to connect to API. Tried with python this:

```
import requests, base64
url = 'https://api-b2b.alzura.com/common/login'
token_req = base64.b64encode(b'name:passwd').decode()
headers = {'Authorization': str(token_req)}
req = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
print(req)
```

And got <Response [400]>, but no token. :D
I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931671/making-an-api-call-in-python-with-an-api-that-requires-a-bearer-token) part about python, but it dint't work for me.

Looks like I does it completely wrong. What should I do/learn/read?

Thank you for your time!

**UPDATE**
It should be a basic auth, and it looks like there is no need any user secrets. Here is little manual from developer:

> Get a login token and expire date. Returns the X-AUTH-TOKEN which is
> required for authentication of the remaining endpoints. Authentication
> for this endpoint is basic auth. For authentication, an
> authentication-header formatted as 'Alzura ID:Password' must be
> transmitted as a base64-encoded string.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p-MBT9640ZxxGBHK_6snzVUS9GimeVgb/view?usp=sharing) to description of obtaining a token. If it could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that a token must be obtained from the server ! A token is required to make some API calls due to security concerns. There are usually at least two types of tokens:

- Access token: You use it to make API calls (as in the Authorization header above). But this token usually expires after a short period of time.
- Refresh token: Use this token to refresh the access token after it has expired.

You should use requests-oauthlib in addition with requests.
https://pypi.org/project/requests-oauthlib/
But first, read the available token acquisition workflows:
https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html#available-workflows
and choose the right workflow that suits your purposes. (The most frequently used is Web App workflow)
Then, implement the workflow in your code to obtain the token. Once a valid token is obtained you can use it to make various API calls.

As a side note: be sure to refresh token if required.

Comment: Do I understand right that client_secret and client_key must be provided by the API owner? It is possible that that API has no client secret and client key?

Comment: You're right: the client id and secret must be provided by the API owner.

Comment: @neznajut Some non-critical API endpoints require no authentication and thus neither client id nor secret. But nowadays, this is extremely unlikely to be the case.