# Python API call

Tags: python, api

I used the following script to make an API call with credentials from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931671/making-an-api-call-in-python-with-an-api-that-requires-a-bearer-token)

```
import requests

username = 'johndoe'
password= 'zznAQOoWyj8uuAgq'

headersAuth = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-length': ''
}

data = {'username': username,'password': password}

## Authentication request

response = requests.post('https://somedomain.test.com/token', headers=headersAuth, data=data, verify=True)
j = response.json()
print(j)

headersAPI = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-length': '',
    'Authorization': j['access_token']
}

# Making sample API call with authentication and API parameters data

response = requests.get('https://somedomain.test.com/api/Users/Year/2020/Workers', headers=headersAPI, verify=True)
api_response = response.json()
```

And when I `print j`, I get `None`. The output is:

```
    j = response.json()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json'
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Please do _never_ include real credentials in your questions, even if the endpoint was hidden here.

Answer (score 0):

In order for us to help more also include error outputs as well. You might be requesting wrong or sending wrong parameters.

Try putting raise_status like below before your response line;

```
response = requests.post('https://somedomain.test.com/token', headers=headersAuth, data=data, verify=True)

response.raise_for_status()

j = response.json()
```

This way you can check if your response is valid or not.

Comment: Thanks Lanre, nothing is returned, so it seems OK. Maybe it could be the Content-Length which is not set?

Comment: You can also print result of it for status  with ; print(response.raise_for_status()

Comment: And since there is problem with your variable j; AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json' . It seems there is no json data returning. I advice you to check your get request if its aligning with api documentation.